# How to get last Firestore ID document

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

i need help with Firestore. I have a database with a collection of Clients that have some documents named by ID (1, 2, 3..)

I want a function that count the number of documents of the collection and create a new document with the value+1 (eg: the last document was 6 and i want a new document 7).

This is what i have done but i don't know why it doesn't work:

```
async function pushName(name, surname) {
  const size = getID('Clients');
  const newID = (size + 1).toString();
  const docRef = firebase.firestore().collection('Clients').doc(newID);
  await docRef.set({
    FirstName: name,
    LastName: surname,
  });
  return(
    <View>
      <Text>name: {name}  </Text>
      <Text>surname: {surname}  </Text>
      <Text>size: {size}  </Text>
      <Text>newID: {newID}  </Text>
    </View>
  );
}

async function getID(){
  
  const snapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('Clients').get().then(function(querySnapshot) {      
    snapshot = querySnapshot.size; 
});
  return snapshot;
}
```

This is the output that i get:

[image]

What i do wrong? How can i do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `getID` doesn't actually return the count.  It returns a promise that eventually resolves with the count.  Since it is async, you will need to `await` its result to get the value.

```
  const size = await getID('Clients');
```

`getID` is also too complicated - you should not mix `await` with `then`.  You can simplify it greatly.

```
async function getID(){  
  const snapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('Clients').get()
  return snapshot.size;
}
```

Comment: It works, thank you so much! Can i ask you another thing? I always receive the warning "Setting a timer for a long period of time..", how can i avoid it?

Comment: If you have a new problem, please post that separately with an explanation of what isn't working the way you expect.